# Pluralization is not working when using translation strings as keys in laravel localization

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-localization

I added this in fr.json

```
{
    "There is one apple|There are many apples": "Hay una manzana|Hay muchas manzanas"
}
```

In blade file:

```
{{__("There is one apple")}}
```

Then it shows

**There is one apple**

It should show **Hay una manzana**. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Did you ever come right? Im experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you set **config/app.php**, as
`'locale' => 'fr'`.
You may set that per request using `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::setLocal('fr');`
within the routes(Route::get()) or maybe using a middleware.

After you set the locale, add this key:value pair to **resources/lang/fr.json** file:
`"There is one apple|There are many apples" : "{1} Hay una manzana|[2,*] Hay muchas manzanas"`.

And instead of `__()` use `trans_choice()` method. And you also have to provide the number of apple/apples as the second argument. That's how it knows if it's going to be singular(1) or plural(2+). So this how you use it inside the blade file:

`{{ trans_choice("There is one apple|There are many apples", 2) }}`.

Answer (score 0):

The default language for your application is stored in the `config/app.php` configuration file's `locale` configuration option. You are free to modify this value to suit the needs of your application.

In your case it should be

```
'locale' => 'fr',
```

You may find more details in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#configuring-the-locale

Comment: I did the same thing, But not working.

Comment: @abhishekvbajaj make sure if you cache config it is up to date `php artisan config:cache` and dump locale in cotroller `dd(App::currentLocale(), true);`